# Image output are not able to show same output result

Tags: image, graph, bufferedimage, imageicon, drawimage

Not sure if it is right or not, but i have a question with showing difference result by using difference way to do it.

My idea: put "Really original.png"(small image) image on the 2.png(large image).

The both code are working fine, but if i tried to comment out the method1's 
`g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` It will only show the "Really Original.png" this part, and other part all black., but why method2 doesn't have this problem??

I also confuse `g.drawImage(Image img,, x, y, Image img,);` In here img will be the small image(Really original.png)??? and x, y are large image(2.png) where i want to put small image in there??

**method1:**

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/TEMP/2.png");
image = icon.getImage();
ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:/TEMP/Really Original.png");
image2 = icon2.getImage();

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
        icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(image2, 0, icon.getIconHeight()-200, null);
```

**method2:**

```
try
{
    File origFile = new File("C:/TEMP/2.png");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(origFile.getPath());
     source = ImageIO.read(origFile);
     logo = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/TEMP/Really Original.png"));

    Graphics g = source.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(logo, 0, icon.getIconHeight()-200, null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `g.drawImage(image2, 0, icon.getIconHeight()-200, null);` Please tell me if i am wrong.  In this line mean: draw the image2(Really Original.png) on the coordinate x=0 and y=0, icon.getIconHeight()-200 of 2.png(large image). If i describe correct, that mean i misunderstand this line before.

Comment: It means "draw `image2`(Really Original.png) onto `g`(from `bufferedImage`) at position x=0, y=width of `icon`(2.png) - 200" (and the last `null` simply means you don't care about image updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason method 2 doesn't have the "problem" with not painting an image doesn't paint the image, is that the `source` image already contains the part you are not painting. If that makes any sense to you (sorry, but it is *really hard* to understand what you are asking).

Comment: Thank you. your last common give me what i wanted. Thank you for much.